# Difference between " InstanceMethod()" and "StaticMethod(ref Type self)" on ValueType?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, clr, cil

```cs
struct Vip
{
    internal int Id;
    internal int Age;
    internal int Weight;
    internal int Position;

    public void Move(int step)
    {
        Position += step;
    }

    public static void Move(ref Vip self,int step)
    {
        self.Position += step;
    }
    
    public static unsafe void MoveFast(Vip* self,int step)
    {
        self->Position += step;
    }
}
```

The first argument in static method plays the role of "this".
I have tested the three methods, and found out the instance method is faster than the method contains "this" explicitly.

What happened under CLR?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll make the description more accurate.

Comment: Most straightforward, common way of writing code is optimised best by the runtime. Not that surprising is it? And any details of why will depend on a great many variables concerning processor and specific version of the JIT you're using.